# How to add an ASP variable inside a JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Post edited with more infos. I have a .asp page that gives me 3 variables. I have no problem working with them. I tried to add a donut chart to show the result using AMCHART charts code. I added the code into my .asp page. The problem is how to add those variables inside the JS code. When I type the variable values directly in the code, the charts are displayed correclty. But I need to add the variable because each customer has its own values...

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>pie-chart test | amCharts</title>
    <meta name="description" content="chart created using amCharts live editor" />

    <!-- amCharts custom font -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Covered+By+Your+Grace' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- amCharts javascript sources -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/chalk.js"></script>


    <!-- amCharts javascript code -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    VAR TOTAL_IPCA;

    <!-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!! -->
              DATA1 = [
                    {
                        "TITULOS": "INFLAÇÃO",
                        "VALORES":  <% = Result_1%>
                },
                    {
                        "TITULOS": "PRÉ-FIXADO",
                        "VALORES": <% = Result_2%>
                    },
                    {
                        "TITULOS": "SELIC",
                        "VALORES": <% = Result_3%>
                    }
                ]


    AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
            {
                "type": "pie",
                "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
                "depth3D": 10,
                "gradientType": "linear",
                "innerRadius": 20,
                "baseColor": "#FF8000",
                "outlineThickness": 2,
                "startEffect": "easeOutSine",
                "titleField": "TITULOS",
                "valueField": "VALORES",
                "fontFamily": "ARIAL",
                "fontSize": 15,
                "handDrawScatter": 1,
                "handDrawThickness": 2,
                "theme": "chalk",
                "allLabels": [],
                "balloon": {},
                "titles": [],
                "dataProvider": DATA1
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300; background-color: #282828;" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are injecting a string you need to encapsulate the ASP variable in double quotes or it will throw a JavaScript syntax error. It should be `"VALUE":  "<%= X%>"`, which will result in the output `"VALUE":  "TOTAL_IPCA"`.

Comment: Where is `X` being set? This code isn't enough to go on. Please provide a [mcve] and encourage you to take a quick look at [ask].

Comment: You say you think "Javascript isn't recognising the <% %> ASP code".  I take it that you do appreciate that ASP is server side (ie rendered by the server) while your Javascript is client side (ie rendered by the browser).  This means that Javascript will never see <% %> delimeters and anything inside them, only the output.  As @Lankymart says we need the code which assigns a value to `x`

Comment: I just updated the question ! Maybe it is more clear now. I have knowledge in ASP but almost zero in JS...sorry.

Comment: It is still not clear where you are assigning values to variables like `Result_1`. Check the source of the page to see if there is any values being printed out. Also press F12 and check the console for any script errors. In the div style, `height: 300;` should be `height: 300px;`

Comment: The result_1 is a record.set from a database filter. For example, if I add <%=result_1%> prior this code, the page will show the result because the variable has a value, but in an .asp recordset. The issue is how can I use this variable into the code above, as Javascript did not understand ASP commands.

Comment: Right click on the page and select "view page source" (or something similar) and see if the values are being printed within the script block. And `VAR TOTAL_IPCA;` should be `var TOTAL_IPCA;`, Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: Is the value for "VALORES" supposed to be an array of values? If `Result_1` is a recordset, you can't simply write it out with `Response.Write` or the `<%=` and `%>` delimiters. The data from each record in the recordset needs to be arranged to look like a JavaScript array. In other words, it will be many lines of ASP code as you iterate through the recordset writing out each value, appropriately delimited.